# Como hacer para que al ejecutar un ciclo for mi aplicación no se blouee vb.net

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Lo que sucede es que tengo una aplicación que toma los archivos de una carpeta y los renombra, hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando se ejecuta la acción la aplicación se queda como congelada hasta que dicha acción termina, pero aún continua trabajando, mi pregunta es como hago para que no se bloquee y se pueda ver un log de lo que va haciendo.
Esto se está haciendo en vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es usar un hilo en segundo plano, por ejemplo, un objeto backgroundworker. Este objeto mientras trabaja en segundo plano (en tu caso renombrando archivos) permite que el proceso principal UI (user interface) no se bloquee. Además te permitiría ir actualizando una barra de progreso según avanza el proceso de renombrar. Te escribo una dirección con un tutorial de los muchos que deben haber [aquí](https://proyectoa.com/crear-proceso-en-segundo-plano-con-barra-de-progreso-en-visual-basic-net-vbnet/).

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1
    Dim nArchTratados As Int32
    Dim archEnCurso As String
    Dim porcentajeMasAlto As Int32 = 0
    WithEvents hiloSegundoPlano As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker


    Function RenombrarArchivos(ByVal ruta As String,
                   ByVal worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker,
                   ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) As Long


        Dim result As Long = 0
        Dim vArchivos() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(ruta, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim numerodeArchivos = vArchivos.Length
        Dim i As Int32
        For i = 0 To vArchivos.Length - 1
            If worker.CancellationPending Then
        'Si el usuario ha pulsado el botón cancelar abortar la operación
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If

            ' Aquí renombraríamos el archivo vArchivos(i)
            archEnCurso = IO.Path.GetFileName(vArchivos(i))

            'Establecemos el % de progreso realizado del total de la tarea
            Dim porcentajeCompletado As Integer
            porcentajeCompletado = CSng(i) * 100 / CSng(numerodeArchivos)
            If porcentajeCompletado > porcentajeMasAlto Then
                porcentajeMasAlto = porcentajeCompletado
                worker.ReportProgress(porcentajeCompletado)
            End If
            nArchTratados = i
        Next
        result = i

        Return result
    End Function


    Private Sub BtnIniciarProceso_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                   ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnIniciarProceso.Click
        If IO.Directory.Exists(lblRuta.Text) = False Then
            lblInfo.Text = "Ruta no hallada."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        barraProgreso.Minimum = 0
        barraProgreso.Maximum = 100

        btnBuscar.Enabled = False
        btnIniciarProceso.Enabled = False

        'Habilitamos el botón cancelar
        'mientras la operación está ejecutándose
        btnCancelar.Enabled = True

        'Iniciamos el valor de la variable que contendrá el % del progreso
        porcentajeMasAlto = 0

        hiloSegundoPlano.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        hiloSegundoPlano.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        'Iniciamos el proceso asíncrono en segundo plano
        hiloSegundoPlano.RunWorkerAsync(lblRuta.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HiloSegundoPlano_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object,
              ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) _
              Handles hiloSegundoPlano.DoWork
        'Obtener el objeto BackgroundWorker que provocó este evento
        Dim worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)

        'Asignar el resultado de la computación a la propiedad Result 
        'del objeto DoWorkEventArgs
        e.Result = RenombrarArchivos(e.Argument, worker, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HiloSegundoPlano_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object,
                ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) _
                Handles hiloSegundoPlano.ProgressChanged
        barraProgreso.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        lblInfo.Text = "Renombrando: " & CStr(archEnCurso)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HiloSegundoPlano_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object,
                 ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
                 Handles hiloSegundoPlano.RunWorkerCompleted
        'Manejar el caso en que se produzca un error o excepción
        If (e.Error IsNot Nothing) Then
            MsgBox(e.Error.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Else
            If e.Cancelled Then
                'Manejar el caso en que el usuario haya cancelado la operación. 
                lblInfo.Text = "Proceso cancelado: " + nArchTratados.ToString() + " archivos tratados."
            Else
                'Manejar el caso en que la operación haya finalizado con éxito
                lblInfo.Text = e.Result.ToString() + " archivos tratados."
                barraProgreso.Value = 0
            End If
        End If


        'Habilitamos el botón de iniciar proceso
        btnIniciarProceso.Enabled = True

        'Deshabilitamos el botón cancelar
        btnCancelar.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtCancelarProceso_Click(
             ByVal sender As System.Object,
             ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancelar.Click
        'Cancelar proceso asíncrono
        hiloSegundoPlano.CancelAsync()

        'Deshabilitar el botón cancelar
        btnCancelar.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnBuscar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscar.Click
        If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            lblRuta.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias gran informacion

Comment: Te agradezco la valoración. Por favor marca como pregunta respondida si así lo consideras.